# SSRS: Displaying current text from column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to display in SSRS the present value from my sharepoint list column. I'm trying to display the person currently on-call today() or now(). Can't get this to work.

```
=Lookup(IIF(Fields!MyField.Value>=Today(),1,0), "My DataSet")
```

Here's my On Call Calendar columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwuYb.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwuYb.jpg

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you're not using the correct parameters for the [Lookup function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx).

The correct way to use this would be as follows:

1. You have a dataset containing dates (e.g., on_call_date) and the name of a single person that's on call for that day (e.g., on_call_name). Let's call this the on_call_dataset.
2. You have a dataset where you're returning a date, possibly today (e.g., reference_date). You want to bring back the person on call in this tablix, so this tablix is the focus and scope of your function.
3. With the data set up as detailed in #1 and #2, the function would be as follows:

   =lookup(Fields!reference_date.value,Fields!on_call_date.value,Fields!on_call_name.value,"on_call_dataset")

Now, if your data isn't set up this way (i.e., in a fashion where you can use one value to find an ***exact*** match in another dataset, then you can't use lookup. In that scenario, I would recommend, instead, building a join into the dataset driving that tablix and returning the appropriate value using SQL logic instead.